# Relations between semi-artinian and $\pi$-regular rings

Tags: ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

A ring $R$ [associative, with 1, **not necessary commutative**] is said to be *right semi-artinian* if every non-zero module over $R$ has a simple submodule.

A ring $R$ is said to be *strongly $\pi$-regular* (*$\pi$-regular*, *right weakly $\pi$-regular*) if for every element $x \in R$ there exists an integer $n>0$ such that $x^n \in x^{n+1}R$ (respectively $x^n \in x^n R x^n$, $x^n \in x^n R x^n R$).

Is it true that every right semi-artinian ring must be: 1) strongly $\pi$-regular? 2) $\pi$-regular? 3) right weakly $\pi$-regular? 4) left weakly $\pi$-regular? Or there are some counterexamples?

P.S. Main results on semi-artinian rings can be found in the following articles:

[1] http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=BSMF_1968_96_357_0 (in French)

[2] http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1971-028-02/S0002-9939-1971-0276259-2/home.html

[3] [Link](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-53/issue-2/On-Loewy-length-of-rings/pjm/1102911603.full)

[4] http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=3085176&fulltextType=RA&fileId=S0013091500022999

(all of them seem to be available free of charge).

Comment: Just a quick question (or request): could you put the concept of "right semi-artinian" into context, i.e. typical applications of this condition, and what is known about it ? Kind regards - Stephan F. Kroneck.

Comment: @bonnbaki: It is hard to give a brief answer. Some usual techniques and main results can be found in the following articles:
[1] http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=BSMF_1968__96__357_0 (in French)
[2] http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1971-028-02/S0002-9939-1971-0276259-2/home.html
(all of them seem to be available free of charge).

Comment: @bonnbaki Years late to the party, of course, but I would say to that question "Many elementary results one learns in classical ring theory for Artinian modules can be done for semi-Artinian modules too." It turns out that semi-Artinian modules generalize both semisimple modules and Artinian modules.

Comment: For some input, the [DaRT](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=177l&L=46) does not currently have evidence that a non-π-regular right semi-Artinian ring exists.  The database does not presently include weakly π regular rings.

Comment: It also seems to be known that right semi-Artinian and π-regular rings are both exchange rings.  (Proves nothing, but is a sort of consistency.)

Answer (score 1):

As a partial answer:

For commutative rings, it is not hard to show that semi-Artinianness implies strong π regularity (which is equivalent to the other two regularities in this case.)

After a bit of digging I found that in

> Lee, Tsiu-Kwen, Zhong Yi, and Yiqiang Zhou. "An example of Bergman's and the extension problem for clean rings." Communications in Algebra 36.4 (2008): 1413-1418.

it was proven that [Bergman's exchange ring that isn't clean](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/rings/ring/70/) is semi-Artinian on both sides, and it is also not strongly π-regular.  This gives one counterexample for that case. However, it is at least π-regular, so the question here is still incomplete for those two cases.